# exibir vários array pelo messageBox.Show no c# ao clicar um botão

Tags: c#, array, matriz

gente to criando um programa pra consultar fornecedores(sendo N fornecedores),e preciso que ao clicar no botão consiga ver todos os fornecedores cadastrados e suas informações da maneira como esta abaixo :

```
nomefornecedor1  telefone1  valordoproduto1 nomefornecedor2  telefone2 valordoproduto2
    .              .           .
    .              .           .
    .              .           .
```

como declarei os vetores

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        string[] Nome = new string[n];               
        string[] Telefone = new string[n];
        float[] ValorCompra = new float [n];`
```

e como estou tentando mostrar ao cliclar no botão

```
private void buttonfornecedores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int linha;    
   {
      MessageBox.Show(Nome[0],Telefone[0],valorcompra[0]);

   }

 }
```

não sei muito de [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) ,então qualquer ajuda agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Se você não sabe a quantidade de elementos que vão entrar nos seus vetores, utilize List ao invés dessa forma (que nem compila).

```
List<string> Nomes = new List<string>();
List<string> Fornecedores = new List<string>();
List<string> telefones = new List<string>();
```

Você não mostra como preenche esses vetores, então vou levar em consideração que você os preenche ao mesmo tempo e que todos tem a mesma quantidade de itens, então a sua implementação deveria ser assim:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.AppendLine("Nome - Fornecedor - Telefone");

            for (int i = 0; i < Nomes.Count; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine($"{Nomes[i]} - {Fornecedores[i]} -{Telefones[i]}");
            }

            MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());           

        }
```

Não está no escopo da pergunta, mas você poderia substituir as listas por uma struct, dessa forma você tem um melhor controle e organização das coisas